# Null values after Post Fields Fill ZIP Code Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

I'm doing a Crud and I'm in trouble, because some fields filled with .val () are not going in the post.

If the filling is manual it up normally.

Can you help me?

VIEW linked to a ViewModel.

```html
@model CRUD.ViewModel.ClienteViewModel



@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, 
new { name = "frm", id = "frm" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DscEndereco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DscEndereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DscEndereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomBairro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomBairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomBairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger",@id="valbairro" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cep, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CidadeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CidadeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CidadeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hdnCep" value=""/>
    </div>

}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>

    $('#Cep').on( "change",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cep = $('#Cep').val().replace("-", "");
        if ($('#hdnCep').val() == cep)
        {
            return false;
        }
        $("#DscEndereco").val('');
        $("#NomBairro").val('');
        $("#CidadeId").val('');
        $("#Estado").val('');

        $.getJSON("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" + cep + "&formato=json", {}, function (data) {

            if (data.resultado_txt = "sucesso - cep completo") {
                $('#hdnCep').val(cep);
                $('#DscEndereco').val(data.tipo_logradouro + ' ' + data.logradouro);
                $('#NomBairro').val(data.bairro);


                $('#CidadeId').val(data.cidade);

                $('#UF').val(data.uf);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

ViewModel

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CRUD.ViewModel
{
    public class ClienteViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
        public string DscEndereco { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
        public string NomBairro { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "CEP")]
        public string Cep { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Cidade")]
        public string CidadeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Crud.Models.Cidade Cidade { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UF { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```html
 // POST: Clientes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            }
```

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Have you narrowed down at all where the error might be occurring? I'd recommend [paring this down to as little code as possible while still reproducing the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do not use code snippets for code you cannot run on this page.  It's only intended for HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: Hello everyone.

I discovered the reason for the fields do not go in POST.

Jquery "disabled" does not send the fields.

I changed to read only and it worked perfectly.

Thank you all!